# How do I center a button in html5?

Tags: css, html, button, center

How do I center a button in html5?
by modify the css file.
I don't want to use the center tag in the html code.

```
a.read{
padding:10px 20px;
font-size:14px;
line-height:20px;
background-color:#eba73c;
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
border-radius:5px;
text-decoration:none;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
clear:both
}
```

Comment: to center something, you give `margin: 0 auto;` to it

Comment: Thank you Pedro but I've already tried it. http://jsfiddle.net/AndersN/YT4Uk/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can apply these styles to the anchor to make it block-level, assign a width, and then adjust its margins like this:

```
a.read{
   display:block;
   width:100px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Or apply this to its parent element:

```
.parent{
   text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use the `<center></center>` tags, they have been removed/ are not valid as of HTML5.

What is parent of your button?

For example if you have :

```
<div class="container">
   <button class="read">A button</button>
</div>
```

You can center it by applying `text-align: center` to the button's parent.

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved it like this http://jsfiddle.net/AndersN/LyX3L/